# dialog modal window not closing when called from child page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use the jQuery UI dialog as pop up window and I wanted to put another aspx page as body  to the Jquery UI Dialog. here I do not want to use the Jquery button option. At the child page, I have put button which is supposed to close the modal window and refresh the parent page. Below is the code I have been trying to implement but some reason I am getting js error message. Am I missing something here ?

Parent Page : aspx page

```
  <div>
     <div id="dialog" title="This is Pop up ">
            <div class="modal">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"  src="childPage.aspx" runat="server" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="open"  id="OpenDialog"/>
    </div>
```

Jquery code : parent page

```
 $(function () {
        var dialog
        dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
        });
        $("#OpenDialog").button().on("click", function () {
            dialog.dialog("open");
        });
    });
```

Child page :

```
 <input type="button" id="btnCloseChildPageRefreshParent" value="Close and Refresh Parent Page" />
```

Child Page Js code :

```
   $(function () {
        $('#btnCloseChildPageRefreshParent').on('click', function () {
            refreshParent();
            open(location, '_self').close();
        });

        function refreshParent() {
            window.opener.location.reload();
        }
    });
```

Comment: did you try `window.parent.location.reload();` ?

Comment: Thanks for correcting  ... got confused on opener and parent

Comment: @LilRazi Be aware though that the domains of the frame and parent must match, or a security error will prevent the reload.

Answer (score 1):

This is an `iframe` so you need to use `window.parent` ([see the MDN documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent)) instead of `window.opener`. It is not a new window, but a frame, so there is no opener.

Note that the domain of the frame and parent must match, or the call will fail due to cross-domain security restrictions.

The code sample below will print out the value of `window.opener` and the error generated by the call to `window.parent.location.reload` to illustrate this.

```js
function log (o) {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.innerHTML = o;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
}

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
  //This line could be used if the domain of the frame and parent match
  //window.parent.location.reload();
    
  log('window.opener is: ' + window.opener);
  
  try {
    window.parent.location.reload();
  }
  catch (e) {
    log('Attempted to call window.parent.location.reload(): ' + e);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Reload Parent</button>
```